# How to pass local file into task parameter in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible, having a simple syntax question, but can't find the answer.

Trying to add certificates to the Java truststore, I use

```
  tasks:
    - name: Install root certificate in Java truststores 
      community.general.java_cert:
        cert_path: ??? 
        cert_alias: mycert
        # this path is linked to both OpenJDK versions, so should work for all
        keystore_path: /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
        keystore_pass: changeit
        state: present
        trust_cacert: true
```

My problem refers to `cert_path` which obviously expects a location in the OS file system, but my certificate is in my Ansible project under `files/mycert.pem`.

Can I pass the file directly into `cert_path` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a new task to copy the certificate file from your local ansible project folder to remote system and then you can provide the cert_path.

Below is the code you can try

```
tasks:
  # Local path to a file to copy to the remote server.
  - name: Copy "mycert.pem" file from local to remote, backing up the original if it differs from the copied version  
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      # src can be relative or absolute path
      src: files/mycert.pem
      # Remote absolute path where the file should be copied to. It can be any path in remote server. I have used /opt/certs as the destination path.
      dest: /opt/certs/mycert.pem
      owner: foo
      group: foo
      mode: '0644'
      backup: yes

  - name: Install root certificate in Java truststores 
    community.general.java_cert:
      cert_path: /opt/certs/mycert.pem
      cert_alias: mycert
      # this path is linked to both OpenJDK versions, so should work for all
      keystore_path: /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
      keystore_pass: changeit
      state: present
      trust_cacert: true
```

For more information for copying file from local to remote, you can check the ansible documentation at
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html

Comment: This works, but I was wondering if there might be a way to do this in one go (without an extra copy task)?

Comment: As per the document the certificate should be available in local or you can use url. I  don't think there is any way to achieve this in one go.